# Usage of NSError deprecated in favor of Error and LocalizedError protocols?

Tags: ios, linux, swift, error-handling

I would like some clarification over the direction of the usage of `NSError` class versus creating a custom enum, struct, or class that conforms to the `Error` or `LocalizedError` protocols. Is it true that the support in Foundation for NSError is there for legacy purposes in order to make the transition easier for converting or interfacing to existing from Swift 2 (or ObjC) code?

For new code, should I just prefer to not use NSError if possible?

To set the context, I mostly develop server-side Linux Swift 3 code not iOS. Although I have experience with iOS development.

Comment: `NSError` is not deprecated. But when writing your own code that throws errors, yes, you'd use `Error`, which is more flexible and expressive. But if calling an existing interface that passes back or throws `NSError`, then obviously feel free to use that `NSError` object.